# Is it fine to remove the /opt/gitlab/ directory manually after removing the gitlab package from the system?

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall, gitlab

I just removed a package from my ubuntu 16.04 system. After removing the package, the terminal shows some warnings like this:

```
Removing gitlab-ce (8.10.4-ce.0) ...
Purging configuration files for gitlab-ce (8.10.4-ce.0)... 
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/sv' not empty so not removed 
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/etc' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/service' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/embedded/ssl/certs' not empty so not removed 
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public' not empty so not emoved 
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/config/initializers' not empty so not removed 
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing gitlab-ce, directory '/opt/gitlab/init' not empty so not removed
```

It says that `/opt/gitlab/` directory is not empty, so it cannot remove those from the system.

Should I delete these directory manually or not?

Comment: You could try renaming it and see if anything _bad_ happens.

Comment: Which gitlab package you installed and removed?

Comment: It was gitlab-ce (community edition), as you can see in the image provided (second line).

Comment: Small thing, but important thing for the life and searchability of this question: Please do not post screenshots of text that can just easily be cut and pasted as code into the question itself. Actual text can be searched and indexed which makes it easier for people with similar problems to find this question and related answers. A screenshot is a screenshot: It’s just a non-searchable picture.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

That directory is populated with `gitlab-ce reconfigure` command after installation and holds variable data, configurations related to `gitlab-ce` package.

The recommended process to uninstall it was

1. Remove services

   ```
    sudo gitlab-ctl uninstall
   ```
2. Clean any data generated by usage of the package

   ```
    sudo gitlab-ctl cleanse
   ```
3. You may also want to remove any accounts you configured. To do so

   ```
    sudo gitlab-ctl remove-accounts
   ```
4. Then remove the package using

   ```
    sudo dpkg -P gitlab-ce
   ```

Furthermore, gitlab-ce uses these directories (as described [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md))

- `/opt/gitlab` holds application code for GitLab and its dependencies.
- `/var/opt/gitlab` holds application data and configuration files that gitlab-ctl reconfigure writes to.
- `/etc/gitlab` holds configuration files for omnibus-gitlab. These are the only files that you should ever have to edit manually.
- `/var/log/gitlab` contains all log data generated by components of omnibus-gitlab.

So, First remove the package recommended way (Even if you need to reinstall it). You can then remove those data using `rm` safely.

<sup>Information found from omnibus-gitlab [README page](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md)</sup>

Comment: This is working even in latest version of Gitlab 12.0.2-ee.0 just with one change: instead of sudo dpkg -P gitlab-ce you should write gitlab-ee

Comment: Yep. Works well but the last step should be ``sudo dpkg -P gitlab-ee``

Answer (score 11):

> Should I delete these directory manually or not?

[Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#OPTADDONAPPLICATIONSOFTWAREPACKAGES) for `/opt/`:

> No other package files may exist outside the /opt, /var/opt, and /etc/opt hierarchies except for those package files that must reside in specific locations within the filesystem tree in order to function properly. For example, device lock files must be placed in /var/lock and devices must be located in /dev.

Anything in `/opt/` is maintained by an uninstall-script that basically does a shutdown of the service (if needed) and a bunch of `rm`'s. So if you want to do that manually you need to shutdown the service (if needed) and then `rm` it.

Mind that `/opt/` has a companion `/etc/opt/` that might contain files related to that package.